# Rpi as driver for an old HP-plotter

Tags: windows

Since windows XP Microsoft was not delivering drivers for pen plotters (*f.e.* HP 7475a). unfortunately also HP stopped to carry about old hardware.

Is there any way to use a Rpi as printer server for this old hardware? The way that I imagine it would be to point raspberry as a -- let say -- network PS-printer and let it drive the plotter via GPIOs.

Some more details: plotter uses parallel printer port.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify what interface the plotter uses. Some older HP plotters used RS-232, or a proprietary connection. Your first challenge will be getting the RPi physically able to communicate over this interface. A USB-Serial adapter might be all you need. Once that's working, I believe you can just send postscript files to the printer. I've not done this myself, so you might want to check out [some of the other howto guides](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jklaas/7475A_howto.txt) for getting this plotter working under linux. Once you get the RPi working with it, you should be able to share the plotter over your network using CUPS+Samba.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I wrote software (on CP/M) for HP Plotters, which have a simple command structure. This is ASCII over RS232.

You should be able to dig up documentation on `HP-GL` (Hewlett-Packard Graphics Language).